# Добавление файлов в проект GitLab из локального репозитория

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull

Не могу разобраться с механикой действия, почему не получается...
Есть файлы в локальном репозитории `git`. Есть проект в `GitLab` (уже содержит файлы, но они отличаются от файлов из локального репозитория). Создала удаленный репозиторий. Необходимо отправить файлы из локального в удаленный.
При потытке сделать push выдает ошибку:

```
" ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ссылка на проект в GitLab'е'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details."
```

Делаю `pull - git` выдает такую ошибку:

```
branch master -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

Comment: Предупреждение: если вы сделаете пулл из удаленного репозитория, то это заменит ваши локальные файлы (в случае успеха, конечно)

Comment: Я из вопроса не понял существенных деталей. Был изначально репозиторий локально, потом создали репозиторий в гитлабе и пытаетесь пропихнуть туда всё с локального компа? Или был проект гитлаб, его склонировали локально, поработали, потом попытались запушить, но оказалось, что репозиторий уехал на N коммитов вперёд?

Comment: @ЕвгенийШалаев, получается, что если я выполню pull, то файлы с сервера Gitlab скопируются в локальный репозиторий, а содержащиеся на тот момент в нем файлы, будут удалены?

Comment: @EkaterinaStebakova не удалены, а перезаписаны те, чтобы есть и на сервере и локально, новые файлы останутся) а чтобы было наоборот, нужно сделать push)

Comment: @ЕвгенийШалаев Дело в том, что файлы в локальном репозитории и удаленном разные. Зада состоит в том, чтобы на сервер добавить файлы из локального. Push не работает... Когда я заливала данные в пустой проект GitLab, всё было ОК

Comment: @EkaterinaStebakova конечно не работает, ведь он понятия не имеет пока что, какие именно файлы ему необходимо добавить. Попробуйте сначала сделать git add . затем git commit -, 'initial commit' а потом git push master

Comment: @EkaterinaStebakova На мой взгляд, лучше сразу пользоваться GitKraken)

Comment: @ЕвгенийШалаев  в локальном репозитории я все команды сделала, подготовила их к отправке на GitLab, даже уже отладила отслеживание веток удаленного и локального репозитория, всё равно выдает ошибку. меня смущает фраза "non-fast-forward" при выполнении push и "refusing to merge unrelated histories" при выполнении pull. Что это значит?

Comment: @AK Есть локальный репозиторий, в котором я веду проект. Мне надо некоторые файлы из этого проекта отправить в проект на Сервер GitLab, чтобы была возможность и в дальнейшем делать обновления моего файла на сервере с помощью команды push

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо всем за помощь. Вопрос был решен следующим образом (может быть кому-то пригодится): 1) удалила все ранее созданные репозитории, 2) создала пустой локальный репозиторий (в папке с репозиторием остались только те файлы, которые мне надо добавить на сервер), 3) затем создала удаленный, 4)выполнила pull, 5)добавила файлы в локальный репозиторий (git add, git commit), 5)сделал push на сервер

Answer (score 0):

Git пишет: `refusing to merge unrelated histories`(отказ от слияния несвязанных историй). Т.е. он не видит связи репозиториев, поэтому не может ни принять в себя внешний репозиторий, ни отправить данные в него.

Локальный репозиторий, похоже, не был создан компированием удаленного. В этом случае вам лучше создать новый репозиторий через `git clone ...`. Либо, если вы уверены, что репозиторий создан корректно, проверьте корректность настройки удаленных репозиторев `git remote`

Comment: В настройках указано, что для pull - master merge with remote master
для push - master pushes to master (local out of date)

Comment: не-не-не, если мы к настройкам пришли, тогда надо проверить, что там. Можете проверить, что пути корректные для удаленного репо?
команда `git remote show origin` (если у вас удаленный репо назван `origin`)

Answer (score 0):

Если вы сначала создали в папке проект а затем на гитхабе и хотите залить ваш локальный проект на сервер - то в вашем случае нужно было сделать следующее:

'######################################

### Upload local repository to github:

'######################################

```
git init
git add . 
git commit -m "First commit"
```

#### Добавляем локальному репозиторию ссылку на удаленный репозиторий github

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/ut4utc/swift.git
```

#### Теперь можно сделать команду push в удаленный репозиторий

```
git push origin master
```

Тем самым отправив вашу локальную ветку master на сервер origin (на github репозиторий).
Теперь вы можете видеть добавленные файлы на github.